# Call to undefined function Store\Model\form_dropdown() in ProductModifier.php on line 84

Tags: expresso-store, ee2

I run EE v2.10.1 with Store 2.5.1. I get the following error when logged in. This error doesn't happen all of the time which puzzles me even more..

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Store\Model\form_dropdown() in [omited]/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/src/Model/ProductModifier.php on line 84

Any clue anyone?

Answer (score 0):

form_dropdown() method is default EE method lies on "form" helper.

Go to the file [omited]/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/src/Model/ProductModifier.php
 and write this line at the beginning of function `ee()->load->helper('form');`

Comment: Like this?> public function toTagArray()
    {   ee()->load->helper('form');
        $attributes = parent::toTagArray();
    etc..

Comment: Yes. Exactly like this.

Comment: Works! I have voted up your answer thx! It seems however strange that this would be required though. Could it be this error hapens because of clustered hosting?

Comment: Glad to here it works.. Its not about hosting... We can say that it is bug of plugin